# Get a block of text in a list of blocks using Regular Expressions

Tags: regex

Edit2: only regex match solutions, please. thank you!

Edit: I'm looking for regex solution, if it's exist. I have other blocks with the same data that are not XML, and I can't use Perl, I added Perl tag as I'm more familiar with regexes in Perl. Thanks in advance!

I Have list like this:

```
<Param name="Application #" value="1">
  <Param name="app_id" value="32767" /> 
  <Param name="app_name" value="App01" /> 
  <Param name="app_version" value="1.0.0" /> 
  <Param name="app_priority" value="1" /> 
</Param>
<Param name="Application #" value="2">
  <Param name="app_id" value="3221" /> 
  <Param name="app_name" value="App02" /> 
  <Param name="app_version" value="1.0.0" /> 
  <Param name="app_priority" value="5" /> 
</Param>
<Param name="Application #" value="3">
  <Param name="app_id" value="32" /> 
  <Param name="app_name" value="App03" /> 
  <Param name="app_version" value="1.0.0" /> 
  <Param name="app_priority" value="2" /> 
</Param>
```

How can I get a block for one app if I only know, say, a value of app_name. For example for App02 I want to get

```
<Param name="Application #" value="2">
  <Param name="app_id" value="3221" /> 
  <Param name="app_name" value="App02" /> 
  <Param name="app_version" value="1.0.0" /> 
  <Param name="app_priority" value="5" /> 
</Param>
```

Is it possible to get it, if other "name=" lines are not known (but there's always `name="app_name"` and `Param name="Application #"`)?

Can it be done in a single regex match? (doesn't have to be, but feels like there's probably a way).

Comment: Oh dear. Get ready for the onslaught of the parser police.

Comment: Rightfully so.  This is NOT suited for a regex.

Comment: Why on Google Earth do you wanna use regex for this? - `Parser Police`

Comment: looking for regex solution. thanks

Comment: because the tool i'm using doesn't have XML parsers, but does have regex match operator.

Comment: @flamey: perl have the XML parsers, it's on CPAN so.

Comment: please read edit - I can only use regex match, that's it.

Comment: the <code>/App02.*?<\/Param>/s</code> will give me second part of what I want. is there a way to get first one?

Comment: -1 When I composed my answer, there was `perl` tag for this question. Now, I find out you cannot use Perl, and you have made up a tag.

Comment: I made up the not-perl tag in response to flamey's edit in the body to indicate that perl is forbidden in the answer.

Comment: I suspect that he meant "Perl-compatible regular expressions" because that's what most text editors offer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer a parser solution, too. If you absolutely *have* to use a regex and understand all the disadvantages of this approach, then the following regex should work:

```
<Param name="Application #"[^>]*>\s+<Param[^>]*>\s+<Param name="app_name" value="App02" />\s+(?:<Param[^>]*>\s+){2}</Param>
```

This relies heavily on the structure present in your example. A re-ordering of tags, introduction of additional tags or (shudder) nesting of tags will break the regex.

Comment: i understand the limitations of your solution, and so far this is the closest to what I want. thank you!

Answer (score 4):

since your content seems to be some XML why don't use a real parser to do the task ?

```
use XML::XPath;
use XML::XPath::XMLParser;

my $xp = XML::XPath->new(filename => 'test.xhtml');

my $nodeset = $xp->find('/Param[@name=\'Application #\']'); # find all applications

foreach my $node ($nodeset->get_nodelist) {
    print "FOUND\n\n", 
        XML::XPath::XMLParser::as_string($node),
        "\n\n";
}
```

you can read a bit more about [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/default.asp) here and have full reference at the [w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath).

I advise you **not** to use reg exp to do that task because it's going to be complicate and not maintenable.

*note*: also possible to use the [DOM API](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML::DOM::XPath) just depend the one you like the most.

Comment: thanks, but i'm looking for regex solution, if it exists - explained-edited in the original.

Comment: +1 for not just saying the mantra, and providing code instead.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a sad case of [***bogus*** XML](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/XML-Abuse.aspx). A misguided attempt to create [enterprisey software](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/XML_vs_CSV__0x3a__The_Choice_is_Obvious.aspx) at best. The developers could have used a sane configuration file format such as:

```
[App03]
app_id = 32767
app_version = 1.0.0
...
```

but they decided to drive everyone insane with meaningless BSXML.

I would say, if this file is less than 10 MB in size, just go ahead and use [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML::Simple). If the file indeed consists of nothing but repeated blocks of ***exactly*** what you posted, you can use the following solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my %apps;

{
    local $/ = "</Param>\n";
    while ( my $block = <DATA> ) {
        last unless $block =~ /\S/;
        my %appinfo = ($block =~ /name="([^"]+?)"\s+value="([^"]+?)"/g);
        $apps{ $appinfo{app_name} } = \%appinfo;
    }
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper $apps{App03};
```

**Edit:** If you cannot use Perl and you won't tell us what you can use, there is not much I can do but point out that

```
/name="([^"]+?)"\s+value="([^"]+?)"/g
```

will give you all `name`-`value` pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it would be more appropriate to use an XML reader library, but I don't know Perl enough to suggest one.

Answer (score 1):

Perl's [XML DOM Parser](http://jonas.liljegren.org/perl/libxml/XML/DOM.html) may be appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using one of XML parsers, but if you cannot do so, then the following quick and dirty code should do:

```
my ($rez) = $data =~/\<Param\s+name\s*=\s*"Application\s#"\s+value\s*=\s*"2"\>((?:.|\n)*?)^\<\/Param\>/m;
print $rez;
```

(assuming $data contains your xml as a single string, possibly multiline )

Comment: this relies on <code>Application #</code>'s value, but i'm looking for <code>app_name</code>. but thanks for your solution.